Build 2D lists of functions and variables in different combinations
Can someone give examples on how to build 2D Lists of function and expressions by the given vectors? I have the following:
V1={a,b,c}; V2={1,2,3}; V3={x1,x2,x3};

How I can build up the following lists:

2D list of functions as to

L1={{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2,b3},{c1,c2,c3}};

L2={{Fa1,Fa2,Fa3},{Fb1,Fb2,Fb3},{Fc1,Fc2,Fc3}};(* having F as a prefix*)


2D list of functions as to

L3={a1[y],a2[y],a3[y]},{b1[y],b2[y],b3[y]},{c1[y],c2[y],c3[y]}}; (*same argument for all functions*)

L3={a1[x1],a2[x2],a3[x3]},{b1[x1],b2[x2],b3[x3]},{c1[x1],c2[x2],c3[x1]}}; (*same argument from V3 for the whole row*)

L4={a1[x1],a2[x1],a3[x1]},{b1[x2],b2[x2],b3[x2]},{c1[x3],c2[x3],c3[x3]}}; (*same argument from V3 for the whole column*)

via Map, Thread or similar functions.
UPD: With the way proposed by @eldo, which I did not expect. I had to specify the question. I am looking the approach to build up the functions list via Map and Thread or similar ones.

Frame challenge: don't use a1, a2, etc. Instead use a[1], a[2] or Indexed[a, 1], Indexed[a, 2], etc. Same for, x, b, x, etc.

Completely agree, thank you for the pointing.

This is a nice exercise for functional programming with: Inner, Outer and MapThread:
v1 = {a, b, c}; v2 = {1, 2, 3}; v3 = {x1, x2, x3};


l1 = Outer[Symbol[ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]] &, v1, v2]
{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}


l2 = Outer[Symbol["F" <> ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]] &, v1, v2]
{{Fa1, Fa2, Fa3}, {Fb1, Fb2, Fb3}, {Fc1, Fc2, Fc3}}


l3 = Outer[Symbol[ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]][y] &, v1, v2]
{{a1[y], a2[y], a3[y]}, {b1[y], b2[y], b3[y]}, {c1[y], c2[y], c3[y]}}


l4 = (Inner[#1[#2] &, #, v3, List]) & /@ l1
{{a1[x1], a2[x2], a3[x3]}, {b1[x1], b2[x2], b3[x3]}, {c1[x1], c2[x2], 
  c3[x3]}}


l5 = MapThread [Function[x, x[#2]] /@ #1 & , {l1, v3}]
{{a1[x1], a2[x1], a3[x1]}, {b1[x2], b2[x2], b3[x2]}, {c1[x3], c2[x3], 
  c3[x3]}}


Thank you. I was updating my post to suggest to do it with Thread or Map, when you reply.  It is very similar to what I was looking for.

Unfortunately with the commands given for L1, L4 and L5 returns either different answer or warnings. What were the vectors v1, v2,v3 you used ?
Outputs I have for your code  is:
L1: {a1, b2, c3}
L2:{{Fa1, Fa2, Fa3}, {Fb1, Fb2, Fb3}, {Fc1, Fc2, Fc3}}
L3:{{a1[y], a2[y], a3[y]}, {b1[y], b2[y], b3[y]}, {c1[y], c2[y], c3[y]}}
L4:Inner::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in Inner[#1[#2]&,a1,{x1,x2,x3},List].
L5: {a1, b2, c3}
Something missed in L1 expression I guess.

Did you note that I used lowercase variables for: v1,v2,v3. I included their definition. And then I copied a wrong line for l1. I fixed it.

Got it. Before it was MapIndexed not the Outer function. Now it works perfectly. Thank you !!!
